# Find a large interval containing no numbers of a random number list

Tags: prolog, intervals

Suppose I have a list of random integer numbers `[x1,..,xn]`.
This list is not sorted, and I want to avoid an algorithm that
sorts, or has the same complexity as sorting.

How would I find an interval `a..b` with `min(xi)<a` and `b<max(xi)`,
so that the interval does not contain any numbers from the list?
Is
there some Prolog algorithm for that, that avoids sorting

complexity? It need not be the greatest interval.

Example:

```
  ?- find([3,17,5,13], I)
  I = 14..16
```

For each `3`,`17`,`5` and `13` we have that these integer numbers are not
contained in the interval `14..16`. But `4..4` could also be a solution,
or `6..12` or smaller intervals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244245/discussion-between-ruben-dias-and-brebs).

Answer (score 1):

```
large_interval(Lst, Lower, Upper) :-
    % Select 2 numbers
    select(Int1, Lst, Lst1),
    select(Int2, Lst1, Lst2),
    Lower is Int1 + 1,
    Upper is Int2 - 1,
    % Break symmetry by imposing order
    Upper >= Lower,
    % Ensure rest of list allows this range
    outside_range(Lst2, Lower, Upper).

outside_range([], _, _).
outside_range([H|T], Lower, Upper) :-
    once(H > Upper ; H < Lower),
    outside_range(T, Lower, Upper).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- findall(Lower-Upper, large_interval([3,17,5,13], Lower, Upper), Pairs).
Pairs = [4-4,6-12,14-16].
```

That finds the *biggest* intervals. Then you can use that list of intervals to create the *smaller* intervals, e.g. 6-12 can split into:

7-12
8-12
9-12
10-12
11-12
12-12
7-11
8-11
9-11
10-11
11-11
etc.

Comment: Looks like a quadratic algorihm O(n^2) with the two select/2. I could also first sort. There are even sort algorithms that are less than quadratic O(n^2), like quicksort tends to be O(n*log(n)).

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear from the beginning, I edited the question a little bit. Hope its now clear. Of course your solution is functionally correct. But challenge lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that seems to be O(*n*) is:

```
find(List, Low-High) :-
    min_list(List, Min),
    max_list(List, Max),
    find(List, Min, Max, Low0, High0),
    Low0 + 1 =< High0 - 1,
    !,
    Low is Low0 + 1,
    High is High0 - 1.

find([], Low, High, Low, High).
find([X|Xs], Low0, High0, Low, High) :-
    (   between(Low0, High0, X)        % split interval
    ->  (   find(Xs, X, High0, Low, High)
        ;   find(Xs, Low0, X, Low, High) )
    ;   find(Xs, Low0, High0, Low, High) ).

test(Length) :-
    Max is 10*Length,
    randseq(Length, Max, List),
    time(find(List, Low-High)),        % check efficiency
    forall(member(X, List),            % check answer correctness
           not(between(Low, High, X))).
```

Examples:

```
?- find([1,2,1,1,3], I).
false.

?- find([1,2,1,9,1,3], I).
I = 4-8.

?- find([3,17,5,13], I).
I = 14-16.
```

**Empirical complexity results**: when list length doubles, running time also doubles.

```
?- test(1000000).
% 8,533,279 inferences, 0.328 CPU in 0.344 seconds (95% CPU, 26006184 Lips)
true.

?- test(2000000).
% 18,483,177 inferences, 0.656 CPU in 0.687 seconds (95% CPU, 28164841 Lips)
true.

?- test(4000000).
% 39,679,989 inferences, 1.328 CPU in 1.337 seconds (99% CPU, 29876698 Lips)
true.
```

Comment: Interesting, a non-deterministic algorithm. Possibly more than O(n), would need maybe run 100, 1000, 10000, etc.. to see whats going on. Not 100% sure. Or maybe the non-determinism is so quickly absorbed, not needed really, only in the tail of the list.

Comment: @RúbenDias I think that, in the worst case, the algorithm has time complexity  O(n^2). But perhaps it will serve as inspiration for a more efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer, that shows that the average length of the
found interval can vary considerably depending on the
algorithm. The results are:

```
/* distance algorithm = slago with heuristic algorithm */
?- aggregate_all((sum(D), count),
        (between(1,1000,_), list(L), find(L, Lo-Hi), D is Hi-Lo+1), (R,C)),
   S is R/1000.
R = 29988, C = 1000, S = 29.988.

/* bisection algorithm */
?- aggregate_all((sum(D), count),
         (between(1,1000,_), list(L), find(L, Lo-Hi), D is Hi-Lo+1), (R,C)),
    S is R/1000.
R = 14162, C = 999, S = 14.162.

/* slago algorithm */
?- aggregate_all((sum(D), count),
          (between(1,1000,_), list(L), find(L, Lo-Hi), D is Hi-Lo+1), (R,C)),
     S is R/1000.
R = 10094, C = 1000, S = 10.094.
```

Here is the slago algorithm;

```
% find(+List, -Interval)
find(L, R) :-
   find(L, 0-999, R), !.

% find(+List, +Interval, -Interval)
find([X|L], Lo-Hi, R) :-
   X < Lo, !, find(L, Lo-Hi, R).
find([X|L], Lo-Hi, R) :-
   X > Hi, !, find(L, Lo-Hi, R).
find([X|L], Lo-_, R) :-
   Lo < X,
   Y is X-1, find(L, Lo-Y, R).
find([X|L], _-Hi, R) :-
   X < Hi,
   Y is X+1, find(L, Y-Hi, R).
find([], R, R).

% list(-List)
list(L) :-
   findall(X, (between(1,100,_), random(1000, X)), L).
```

Then a bisection algorithm, replace the 3. and 4. clause by:

```
find([X|L], Lo-Hi, R) :-
   M is (Lo+Hi)//2, X < M, M =< Hi, !,
   find(L, M-Hi, R).
find([_|L], Lo-Hi, R) :-
   M is (Lo+Hi)//2-1, Lo =< M,
   find(L, Lo-M, R).
```

And then distance algorithm, which is slago with heuristic:

```
find([X|L], Lo-Hi, R) :-
   X-Lo > Hi-X, Lo < X, !,
   Y is X-1, find(L, Lo-Y, R).
find([X|L], _-Hi, R) :-
   X < Hi,
   Y is X+1, find(L, Y-Hi, R).
```